# IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm having a hard time trying to connect to my institution's MQ v9.

I was provided connectivity info by the MQ team:-

```
String hostName = '...'
int port = ...
String queueManager = '...'
String channel = '...'
String userId = 'ABC123'
String password = '...'
```

Given the following code...

```
JmsConnectionFactory cf = JmsFactoryFactory.
        getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER).
        createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, userId)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password)
// tried with both `true` and `false`... same error
cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true)

Connection connection = cf.createConnection()
connection.start()
connection.close()
```

... I'm getting this error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: 
JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid 
that was supplied for queue manager '...' with connection 
mode 'Client' and host name '...'.
Please check if the supplied username and password 
are correct on the queue manager to which you are 
connecting.  
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM 
MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason 
'2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

I was told by the MQ team that the log has something like this:-

```
----- amqzfuca.c : 4527 -------------------------------------------------------
04/17/2019 10:32:20 AM - Process(10468.40757) User(...) Program(...)
                    Host(...) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.0.1) QMgr(...)
                    Time(2019-04-17T15:32:20.542Z)
                    RemoteHost(...)
                    CommentInsert1(...)
                    CommentInsert2(...)
                    CommentInsert3(CLNTUSER(XYZ) ADDRESS(...))

AMQ9777E: Channel was blocked

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel '...' was blocked from address '...' 
because the active values of the channel matched a record
configured with USERSRC(NOACCESS). The active values of the channel were
'CLNTUSER(XYZ) ADDRESS(...)'.
```

... and it fails because it's using the wrong credential to connect.

While I passed in a different credential (user ID: ABC123), the MQ log sees the user ID I used to log into my machine (user ID: XYZ).

Why does the credential I explicitly passed in get omitted? How do I fix this?

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not using IBM JRE... more precisely, I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8 on my Mac, if that helps.

Thank you.

**UPDATE 2019-04-22**

I was able to get more accurate logs from MQ team now since I'm trying too many things at the same time.

If I set `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to `true`, then my machine's user ID (XYZ) is passed in.

If I set `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to `false`, then I'm getting different error message now:-

```
04/22/2019 01:19:49 PM - Process(1147099.9759) User(...) Program(...)
            Host(rofesb911a) Installation(Installation1)
            VRMF(9.1.0.1) QMgr(...)
            Time(2019-04-22T18:19:49.323Z)
            RemoteHost(...)
            CommentInsert1(wa03598)
            CommentInsert2(REQUIRED)
            CommentInsert3(MCAUSER(ABC123) CLNTUSER(ABC123) ADDRESS(...))

AMQ9790I: The failed authentication check was caused by a CHLAUTH record with
CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED).

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'ABC123' and its password were checked because the inbound
connection matched a channel authentication record with CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED).

The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(ABC123) CLNTUSER(ABC123)
ADDRESS(...)'. The MATCH(RUNCHECK) mode of the DISPLAY CHLAUTH
MQSC command can be used to identify the relevant CHLAUTH record.
```

The good news is it's seeing the correct user ID (ABC123), but I was told the password is invalid. I don't believe it was a password problem because I was able to use that same credential to access other protected web services.

Comment: Does the queue manager connauth object have `ADOPTCTX(YES)`?  Does the `CLNTUSER` value of the channel change depending on how you set `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP`?  Can you provide all the `CHLAUTH` rules for that channel?

Comment: What is the length on the value specified in the `USERID` property?

Comment: @JoshMc, I'm currently in the process of getting verification that `ADOPTCTX(YES)` is used. Unfortunately, the queue setup is a total blackbox to me since it's handled by a different team. The `USERID` value length I explicitly passed in is 7 characters long.

Comment: Have them carefully check the error when you have csp set to false.

Comment: I was told they have `ADOPTCTX(YES)` configured.

Comment: Can you check to see if they have `ChlAuthEarlyAdopt=Y` in the `qm.ini`?  Without this, the `CHLAUTH` rules only act against the user you run the process as not what you ass as the `USERID` if you are setting `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP=true`.  If you set `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP=false` then it should not matter and the `CHLAUTH` would be fine.

Comment: I was told `ChlAuthEarlyAdopt=Y` is set in `qm.ini`. As far as I know setting `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` true or false isn't doing anything for me. @JoshMc do you know on top of your head if I need to override certain system property from client side since I'm using non-IBM JRE?

Comment: Are you sure the error with `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP=false` is the same user?   Have you tried with not setting it at all, this should default to false, but it is worth a try to see if the behavior is different.

Comment: Can you ask your MQ team to check for any errors like `AMQ5534: User ID 'ABC123' authentication failed`?  If you have `ChlAuthEarlyAdopt=Y` set, then MQ will attempt to authenticate the MQCSP id/pw (ex: `ABC123`) before checking CHLAUTH rules.  if the authentication at this stage fails, then MQ will drop through to the CHLAUTH rules with the user the process is running as (ex: `XYZ` not the one passed in the MQCSP.  The `AMQ9777E: Channel was blocked` error you receive would make sense if this was the case only if you have `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP=true` as both IDs are passed to the server..

Comment: If you have `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` unset or set to `false`, then only id that would be passed to the server would be `ABC123`, so no matter of the pre-`CHLAUTH` authentication failed or not the blocked error would never be against the `XYZ` user.  These comments also hinge on `CHLCLNT(REQUIRED)` being set either via the `CONNAUTH`'s `AUTHINFO` object or via a `CHLAUTH` rule.  I asked before:  Can you provide all the CHLAUTH rules for that channel?, this would be a helpful update to the question along with the `CONNAUTH` object.  Note that wildcard rules that would match are also needed.

Comment: Also check that you are not setting the Java System Property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication` to either `Y` or `true`.  Also check that you are not setting `useMQCSPauthentication=YES` the JMQI stanza of a `mqclient.ini` file that is picked up by your program, there are various locations MQ will look for this file documented in the Knowledge Center.  I also noted that in most examples when referencing the JMS property `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` they use `JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` not `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP`.

Comment: @JoshMc, I updated my post above. With `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to `false`, I get different error message back.

Comment: Then it looks like a match for what I mentioned above.  When you specify true, the MQCSP user check fails before the CHLAUTH rules and the CHLAUTH rules are applied against the machine user.  When you specify false it just shows the authentication failed since that failure "trumps" the CHLAUTH failure.  I would be surprised if it does not show a `AMQ5534` or `AMQ9790` error around the `AMQ9777` error when you do specify `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to `true`

Comment: Depending on the `AUTHINFO` object setting `AUTHENMD`, if you have access to the server where MQ runs you can test if the user and password values that you have would pass.  If `AUTHENMD(OS)` then run `echo 'password'|/opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax ABC123`, the output if successful should be `+0 [OK]`.  If `AUTHENMD(PAM)` then run `echo 'password'|/opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoampx ABC123`, the output if successful should be `+0 [NULL]`.  If you see any other output MQ is not able to authenticate the user.  Does the MQ server successfully authenticate any other users?

Comment: Is it possible the username needs to be lowercase vs UPPERCASE?  Many authentication systems are case sensitive.

Comment: Is it possible that your password is greater in length than 12 characters? Using USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP set to false restricts how long your password can be.

Comment: Noted your comment from your blog. If you have more specifics on what was misconfigured to produce the results you experienced I think it would be a good addition as a self answer or an update to your question. You have me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MQ team have given you the credentials to use (i.e. user id and password) so I would assume that they have turned on user id and password checking on the queue manager.

#### Queue Manager is not using ADOPTCTX(YES)

ADOPTCTX(YES) is a setting on the queue manager that indicates that once user id and password have been verified as being correct, the user id (in your case "ABC123") should then be used for all further security checks (e.g. am I allowed to use this queue). If this setting is NO, then after the password validation is complete, it will actually use the client machine logged on user id which is also sent up to the queue manager (in your case "XYZ"). It seems likely that this is the case on your queue manager.

#### USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP mode

There are actually two ways that a user id and password can be sent from a Java client application to the queue manager.

1. The first (decades old) was in use prior to IBM MQ V8, and used a restricted length flow (12 chars max each field) that was originally there for DOS SNA clients to send the two fields to the QMgr. This flow across the network was also the way the client logged on user id got sent to the queue manager, and so only one could be sent.
2. The newer one, added in MQ V6, and made more useful with password checking natively in the queue manager in MQ V8, was the MQCSP structure, which allowed for variable length user id and password fields. This was a different network flow from the one that sends the client logged on user id, and so both are sent to the queue manager.

When you set `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to true, you were telling the Java client to use the second mode. This gives the opportunity to be tripped up by the ADOPTCTX(NO) setting. If you set it to false, the only user id that makes it to the queue manager is ABC123 (in your example) and will likely give you a different, perhaps successful result.

Try your application with `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to false, and when it works, advise your MQ team that they should use ADOPTCTX(YES) which is also now the default value, then you can switch back to `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to true.

Comment: I did try setting `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to `false`, but I get the same error message. So, I assume my only option right now is to have them check whether they are using `ADOPTCTX(YES)`? Thank you.

Comment: When you say you get the same error message, do you mean that you get the same return code (2035) or that the error message on the queue manager is the same, i.e. it still shows your client machine user id XYZ?

Comment: The error message I'm getting is 2035, and on MQ log, it is still showing user ID XYZ instead of the credential I passed in.

Comment: That sounds rather like it is ignoring USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP or possibly doesn't know how to use MQCSP at all. What version of client are you using?

Comment: I was told the MQ server version is 9.1.0.1. I'm using this Maven dependency: com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.1.2.0

Comment: I updated my post above. With `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to `false`, I'm getting different error.

Comment: You accepted this answer,  what was the problem?  You previously stated that you already tried both suggestions made by Morag, did something change to make this a solution to your original problem?

Comment: @limc nice post: https://myshittycode.com/2019/04/23/spring-boot-connecting-to-ibm-mq-over-jms-using-non-ibm-jre/.  Morag might be a good one for your MQGem Monthly.